# coming back to splashscreen in eclipse rcp

Tags: java, eclipse, screen, rcp, splash-screen

I have an RCP program with a splash screen with a login.

I'd like to make a log out button. By clicking this button, the user should be referred back to the splash screen, so he has to log in again..

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench.restart()` it will go back and run the splash screen again.